# Can I port Glassfish jdbcRealm to JBoss?

Tags: jboss, glassfish, jdbcrealm

My application is running on Glassfish 3.1 using jdbcRealm is its authentication and authorization. I want to port this app to JBoss 6. Can I create a jdbcRealm inside JBoss 6 like in Glassfish3 that map to a USER table in my database? Can I do it via admin-console? In JBoss, I figure out how to create database connection (just by create datasource), but in Glassfish I also set up JavaMail Sessions in Glassfish with `jndi`, `mail-host`, `transport protocol`..., can I port that over to JBoss as well?

Comment: Did you get the jdbcRealm ported to glassfish? i'm about to try that now. I found this for jboss 3.0.x but i'm using jboss 6 also: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm if this technique still works i'd like to know where to stick the server.xml file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers on your questions:

> Can I create a jdbcRealm inside JBoss
>   6 like in Glassfish3 that map to a
>   USER table in my database?

If I understand correctly you use database to authenticate users?

You can define something like that in JBoss. The easiest way is to add proper security domain definition to the `conf/login-config.xml` file.

It can looks like that:

```
<application-policy name="database-domain">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
      <module-option name="dsJndiName">java:/yourDataSource</module-option>
      <module-option name="principalsQuery">select password from users where userid = ?</module-option>
      <module-option name="rolesQuery">select role, 'Roles' from roles where userid = ?</module-option>
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

You should also create proper data source and put database library to the `lib` directory.

> Can I do it via admin-console?

I do not know if it is possible to make these changes using web console.

> In JBoss, I figure out how to create
>   database connection (just by create
>   datasource), but in Glassfish I also
>   set up JavaMail Sessions in Glassfish
>   with jndi, mail-host, transport
>   protocol..., can I port that over to
>   JBoss as well?

JBoss use default database to store some information. If you want to change that the simples way is to define new data source with the `DefaultDS` name and delete the `deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml` file.

In JBoss 6 they change JMS provider and it also use its own DB to stre some info, bu I don't know if and how to change it.